# Write in internal flash memory of STM32

Tags: embedded, stm32

I can't write in the flash as `pFlash.ErrorCode` I get the value `136`.

```c
uint32_t writeval(uint32_t src_address){
    uint8_t test=1;
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    uint32_t writeaddr=0x08008000;
    
    if(HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_QUADWORD, writeaddr, (uint32_t)&test) != HAL_OK)
    {
        return HAL_ERROR;
    }
    
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    return HAL_OK;

}
```

I expect to be able to write the value of the test variable in the flash address `0x08008000`

Comment: Which exact STM32 are you using? Did you erase the flash page that contains that address? If that address does not contain all 0xff then the programming will fail.

Comment: yes i erase the page that contain the address

'
 HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
 uint32_t PAGEError;

 static FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
 EraseInitStruct.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
 EraseInitStruct.Page = 0;
 EraseInitStruct.Banks = FLASH_BANK_1;

 if(HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK)
  return HAL_ERROR;
'
(i use the page 0 because i have change the address)
i use the U575ZI-Q

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the additional code, rather than putting it in the comments. What do you mean "i use the page 0 because i have change the address"? You should check the return values from every HAL function that you call. Maybe the erase is failing.

Comment: open in debugging mode, open SFR special function registers, find FLASH, find its status register (typically, but not necessarily, called SR or ISR), and check the value in the status register. Some flags will be set, they should point to what exactly event went wrong. Also, the full name of the MCU would be nice to have

Comment: i have resolved! it didn't erase the memory because i didn't use all the fields of the struct, i omitted "NbPages", now it erase and write, thank you all for the help!